Is this sentence from the Dexter TV series an example of a choriamb?
Wikipedia says that a choriamb is a prosodic foot (used in verse) ”consisting of four syllables in the pattern long-short-short-long (— ‿ ‿ —)”. But because I am not a native English speaker, the English concepts of lexical and prosodic stress are unclear to me. I would therefore like to know whether the following sentence said by Lila’s character in the Dexter television series is an example of a choriamb:

Pardon my tits.

I think it is such but am seeking confirmation.
Using an acute accent to indicate stressed syllables, I think that that line would be stressed this way if it were a choriamb:

Párdon my títs. (— ‿ ‿ —)

But it would not be a choriamb if it were stressed in any of these various ways:

Párdon mý tits. (— ‿ — ‿)
Pardón my títs. (‿ — ‿ —)
Pardón my tits. (‿ — ‿ ‿)
Pardon mý tits. (‿ ‿ — ‿)
Pardon my títs. (‿ ‿ ‿ —)

And so on and so forth.
How can I know which way to say this, or even which way it was said by the TV character in the audio? My own ear does not pick up on this in English because of differences between how English works and how my own native language works in this regard.

For what use it is - yes, obviously "pardon my tits" manifests the "dah-di-di-dah" prosody sometimes labeled "choriamb" in certain poetic / Lit Crit contexts. What makes you think it might not? Not that I know anything about this source, but I doubt the stress is expected to fall as "Pardon my tits!" (but not hers!)

I don't think it's a "typical" utterance for that prosody, because the actual use in poetry is likely to put either equal stress on first and last, or - perhaps more often - primary stress on the first. But in "pardon my tits", it's the final syllable that almost unavoidably gets primary stress. (Partly because of that very "memorable crudity", I suggest! :)

It fits the pattern but I doubt the script's authors were writing in verse.

Yes.
By "long" you mean stressed syllable, and by short you mean an unstressed sylable. By that definition:
par- (stressed)
-don (unstressed)
my (unstressed)
tits (stressed)

Choriamb is applicable only to poetry in which the rhythm and beat of the written word can be calculated.
In the written form of simple speech, it is not possible to classify the phrase as you have not heard it spoken and there is no other clue.
